# How can I convert each cell in HTML table column to a downloadable link, that references a local zip file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently designing a web application that would read an XLSX file and convert it into an HTML table. The XLSX file contains columns that is concatenated into the "Info" column

I have three columns, "FileName", "Info", "Download", that becomes populated with a for loop. In this for loop, I would like to add a link in each cell under the "Download" column, that references a zip file in my local directory.

I have already tried createElement('a') within my loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
    //Add the data row.
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    //Add the data cells.
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);

    if(headerCell.getElementById = 'FileName'){
    cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].FileName;
    //cell.setAttribute("id", "FileName");

    }
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Title + " ; " + excelRows[i].Summary + " ; " + excelRows[i].Author;

    if(headerCell.getElementById = 'Download'){
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);



    cell.innerHTML = document.createElement('a');
      //cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].FileName + ".zip";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = excelRows[i].FileName + ".zip";
a.innerText = 'Some Link';

cell.appendChild(a);
```

or

```
cell.innerHTML += '<a href="' + excelRows[i].FileName + '.zip">Some Link</a>';
```